# How can I allow a Vue component to manage its own transitions?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

By this I mean, when mounted, the enter animation is ran, and when removed, the leave animation is ran. I have a transition that needs to animate a number of elements within it on enter and leave, so I want to move all the code into its own component, then

```
<template>
    <transition @enter="enter" @leave="leave">
        <!-- component -->
    </transition>
</template>

---

<CustomComponent :key="indentifer" :indentifer="indentifer" />
```

Full example of my attempt: https://codesandbox.io/s/znq6l8p94p

As far as I am aware this is only half working because of the `appear`, i.e. it's just mere coincidence.

I feel like the only way I can solve this is by doing all the animation and state management in one component, as in a component that knows about the old and new sentences or use a `transition-group`, rather than just leaving Vue to manage that for me via my use of the `key` attribute. Am I perhaps misunderstanding how best to do transitions in Vue, should the animation all ways reside with the parent of a component?

After writing this out it feel like what I actually want is lifecycle hooks like `transition-group` offers, but which call the child components methods directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current understanding is that during `v-on:leave` the component is no longer reactive, and you should only be doing manual dom-manipulation...

Instead, my solution was to create a component that handled the adding and removing of the elements via a `watch` and then passed the array through to my component in `props`.